# Question about the paper of Soundararajan and Radziwill on Selberg's CLT for $\log|\zeta(1/2+it)|$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The paper: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/radziwill/CLTNotes3.pdf.

Briefly, I'm having trouble inferring the moments given at the end of Proposition 2 from Lemma 1. I'm going by splitting the integrands into real and imaginary parts, and then expanding into products of the real and imaginary parts of $\mathcal{P}_0$ itself. I run into a jungle of binomial coefficients as coefficients of $(\Re\mathcal{P}_0)^n(\Im\mathcal{P}_0)^{k-n}$, where I'm trying to show that appropriate linear combinations of $|\mathcal{P}_0|^n\Re(\mathcal{P}_0^{k-n})$ give the final results.

In the odd cases any combination of integrals with $k\neq l$ will do, so we just need existence, while in the even case of $k$ (using the $k$ they have after the lemma) we need particular combinations starring $\mathcal{P}_0^k$ to give us the new coefficient in the main term. Is this a good path, in which case how does one follow it? Or am I going in too messy a direction, in which case how should I really be thinking of this?

Comment: Just write $(Re P_0)^k = (P_0(\sigma_0+ it) + P_0(\sigma_0-it))^k/2^k$ and expand using the binomial theorem.  Only the middle binomial coefficient survives.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. Thanks!